# Pandas DataFrame: assigning values to multiple separate elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following dataframe:

```
           Well_ID  BOPD
Date                    
2020-01-01     101     1
2020-01-02     102     2
2020-01-03     102     3
2020-01-04     101     1
2020-01-05     103     2
2020-01-03     101     3
```

which I would like to reformat into:

```
            101  102  103
2020-01-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
2020-01-02  NaN  2.0  NaN
2020-01-03  3.0  3.0  NaN
2020-01-04  1.0  NaN  NaN
2020-01-05  NaN  NaN  2.0
2020-01-06  NaN  NaN  NaN
2020-01-07  NaN  NaN  NaN
2020-01-08  NaN  NaN  NaN
2020-01-09  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Which I can obtain using the for loop:

```
for well, date, bopd in zip(wellTest['Well_ID'].tolist(),wellTest.index.to_list(),wellTest['BOPD'].to_list()):
    wellTestBr.loc[date, well] = bopd
```

Really think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `pivot`:

```
df.reset_index().pivot('Date', 'Well_ID', 'BOPD')

Well_ID     101  102  103
Date
2020-01-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
2020-01-02  NaN  2.0  NaN
2020-01-03  3.0  3.0  NaN
2020-01-04  1.0  NaN  NaN
2020-01-05  NaN  NaN  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['Well_ID'], append=True)['BOPD'].unstack()
```

Output;

```
Well_ID     101  102  103
Date                     
2020-01-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
2020-01-02  NaN  2.0  NaN
2020-01-03  3.0  3.0  NaN
2020-01-04  1.0  NaN  NaN
2020-01-05  NaN  NaN  2.0
```